# Is PHP on Laravel really that bad for high traffic

Tags: php, laravel, scalability

I originally asked a biased question about which MVC framework is best suited for high traffic.

The answer to this question is that most frameworks can are designed handle such traffic. Choose the best MVC framework you are comfortable  with.

Comment: If building for success disables you from building anything at all, I would much rather build for failure and refactor, then never make a thing. The question is horribly biased and silly; and should be closed.

Comment: This question is quite opinion based, but imho developing for such a scale so early on will only make your life miserable. And if worried about PHP and its scalability you can make everything work. You can refer to Youporn which handles immense amount of traffic on a Symfony backend ([reddit post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/2/youporn-targeting-200-million-views-a-day-and-beyond.html) / [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlkCdM_f3p4)).

Answer (score 2):

Donald Ervin Knuth:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming.

Most of the tools we're using (including frameworks in general and Laravel in particular) are designed to speed up development process and *then* ease developers workflow.

The general rule here I'd say is build it first. By the moment your project becomes so big (read successful) that Laravel on PHP7 fails to deliver you certainly will be able to hire someone to tackle that problem.

Therefoe Laravel is a decent choice for a new project, like any other framework.

Ideally write your application logic in a framework-agnostic manner, i.e. keep Laravel out of your business logic - that requires some experience, but in the end you would even be able to switch frameworks.